# Unix: looking for an alternative command to exclude the semicolon in the end

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to know if there is an alternative to:

find -name "*broken*" -exec rm '{}' ';'

I want to avoid the semicolon in the end.

I'm looking for a solution to exclude the semicolon. When i just remove it it does not work.
First I want to list certain files and let them be displayed before deleting them.
This should work for all directories and subdirectories. And the "|" (i think its called pipe) and it does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `;` is part of one of the two supported `find -exec` syntaxes so you cannot remove it:

> **-exec** utility_name [argument ...] **;**
>
> **-exec** utility_name [argument ...] **{} +**
>
>      The end of the primary expression shall be punctuated by a <semicolon> or by a <plus-sign>. *[...]*

In certain cases (like yours) you might want to replace the semi-colon with a `+` (see bellow).

---

> First I want to list certain files and let them be displayed before deleting them

With GNU `find`:

```bash
find -name "broken" -print -delete
```

With standard `find`:

```bash
find . -name "broken" -print -exec rm -- {} +
```

Comment: hey :) thank you very much. I'm still figuring out how to correctly type it in but thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @Sizzurpp I got interrupted while updating my answer; check it now for a practical solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks again I managed to finish my assignment thanks to you :))))))